# Auto-complete a Single created from another Observable

Tags: rx-java2

I have a long-running operation that returns a value in code I don't control. I need that value to be published to things that ask for it. For this purpose I am using a `BehaviorSubject`:

```
var subject: Subject<Value>? = null

fun retrieveValue(): Single<Value> {

    if (subject == null) {
        subject = BehaviorSubject.create<Value>()

        someOtherThing.retrieveValueAsync { value ->
            subject.onNext(value)
        }
    }

    return subject.singleOrError()
}
```

This lets me perform the operation only once and send the result as a single to all future interested parties. However, it does not work. The single will not emit a value until I call:

```
subject.onComplete()
```

But this is a problem because once the subject is completed future things can no longer subscribe to it.

What is the appropriate way to cache a value from another observable and pass it to a Single? If there was a way to have a subject automatically complete once its source observable emitted a value that would work. `Single.cache()` also looks promising, but I'm unsure how I would handle the fact that my value comes in asynchronously in that case.

It feels like I'm missing something silly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a [`SingleSubject`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/subjects/SingleSubject.html) for this case.

If you don't want experimental code in your codebase, you can use `ReplaySubject.createWithSize(1)` and call `onComplete` without losing the last value, then convert it to `Single`.